# What is the difference between sessions, cookies, and persistent storage in ElectronJS?

Tags: electron

I am trying to build an app with ElectronJS.

However, I am having a difficult time trying to understand the difference between sessions, cookies, and persistent storage?

The documentation does not offer much explanation. Can someone be kind enough to explain to me when to use Sessions, Cookies, and Persistent Storage.

Also, can I store sessions and cookies in persistent storage?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cookies and sessions are both designed for authentication. The difference between them is the user data of  cookies stored in the browser (sent in the request headers), the session just stored the key of the user data, actual data was stored in the background process.
persistent storage is used to store data (any data).
Also you can store sessions and cookies in persistent storage if you like.